# free cloud or on promise sw for customer support

Tags: gratis, open-source, web-apps, support-tracker

I a looking for a **free** customer support (help desk + knowledge base)

- for small team
- for multiple products
- with multi-language support (English + Czech is a must)
- submission of tickets (and preferably updates) via email and web UI
- custom fields
- agent permissions per product

I did my search and HESK and osTicket looked promissing but it is not a peferct match. The same for Zoho Desk, Spiceworks etc